# Trying to make my iphone app universal. Navigation Controller keeps saying Unbalanced calls

Tags: iphone, controller, navigation, stack

have been trying couple of hours now to make my iphone app universal. The mission was successful but have a strange problem. The navigation controller keeps pushing things without even pushing anything. The app doesn't crash but it gives me a message in the console

`nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-02-06 10:52:07.701 @#$%^^$[54755:207] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-02-06 10:52:07.704 !@#$%^$%#[54755:207] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <searchEditViewController: 0xc652150>.`

and here is how i've set app the whole thing :

![navigation screen shot][1]

here is my code in the AppDelegate_iphone.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iPhoneView.h"
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"
#import "FavoritesViewController.h"

@class iPhoneView;

@interface AppDelegate_iPhone : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    UINavigationController *homeNavigationController;
    UINavigationController *favouritesNavigationController;
    AboutUsViewController *aboutUsViewController;

    iPhoneView * search;
    FavoritesViewController *favoritesViewController;
    UIWindow *window;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iPhoneView *search;
@property (nonatomic, retain) FavoritesViewController *favoritesViewController;

@end
```

and here is on my AppDelegate.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate_iPhone.h"
#import "iPhoneView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate_iPhone

@synthesize window,search,favoritesViewController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{   tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    search = [[iPhoneView alloc] init];
    [homeNavigationController pushViewController:search animated:NO];

    favouritesNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    favoritesViewController = [[FavoritesViewController alloc]init];
    [favouritesNavigationController pushViewController:favoritesViewController animated:NO];

    aboutUsViewController =[[AboutUsViewController alloc] init];

    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"επικοινωνία" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aboutus"] tag:0];
    aboutUsViewController.tabBarItem = item;
    [item release];

    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"αγαπημένα" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites"] tag:0];
    favouritesNavigationController.tabBarItem = item2;
    [item2 release];

    NSArray *tabBarControllerCollection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavigationController,favouritesNavigationController,aboutUsViewController,nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:tabBarControllerCollection animated:NO];

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called as part of  transition from the background to the inactive state: here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Free up as much memory as possible by purging cached data objects that can be recreated (or reloaded from disk) later.
     */
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [tabBarController release];
    [search release];
    [favoritesViewController release];
    [favouritesNavigationController release];
    [aboutUsViewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK solved had connected the button 2 times with the same action in IB. Took me 48hours to figure it out!